# Qt Warning: QQmlComponent: Component is not ready

Tags: qml, qt5

Is it possible to get Qt error messages when using dynamically created items?

I've installed a message handler to capture Qt output at run time:

```
qInstallMessageHandler( myMessageOutput );
```

I load a basic qml file into a QQuickView and it works fine. If there are errors in the qml source they're displayed in my log. If I dynamically create items and they contain errors it fails without any message.

I create the dynamic objects like this:

```
var component = Qt.createComponent( "config.qml" );
var dlg = component.createObject( parentId, {} );
```

The only error I receive is the following:

```
'qml\qqmlcomponent.cpp':845 function: 'QObject* QQmlComponentPrivate::beginCreate(QQmlContextData*)'|Qt Warning: QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
```

This error is written for any kind of problem in the qml it's trying to load.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should read and follow [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html).

What you do not check is that [`component.status`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#status-prop) must be equal to `Component.Ready` before calling to `component.createObject`.

If the file somehow failed to load, as it does not parse correctly, `component.status` will be equal to `Component.Error`, and you should call [`errorString()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#errorString-method) to get more information.

```
var component = Qt.createComponent( "config.qml" );
if( component.status != Component.Ready )
{
    if( component.status == Component.Error )
        console.debug("Error:"+ component.errorString() );
    return; // or maybe throw
}
var dlg = component.createObject( parentId, {} );
```

Anyway you should always assert `component.status == Component.Ready` before calling `createObject()`.

Comment: Missed that part of the documentation. Thanks

Comment: Yow. That's scary. I don't *think* I've hit that but it's very good to know.

Comment: I think I've figured out a work around for the bug in asynchronous loading. Use the QML Loader element to begin loading of a QML file. In the qml file use the onCompleted signal to cause it to be displayed.

Comment: Dynamic loading using the loader element seems to work well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390703/qtquick-dynamic-object-in-a-different-context/18409609#18409609

Comment: this is not factually correct as to what qt officially states. they say that "if you're certain it's a local file" that you could call it immediately. however, there's some buggage there, it seems

Comment: seriously , bless you !

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error when showing new window because it used `QtQuick.Layouts` but the module was not installed. Installing `qml6-module-qtquick-layouts` package solved the issue